# AngularJS vs MVC controllers What to choose?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

So Im starting with AngularJs and i see you can create controllers and modules in AngularJS scripts. My app runs on asp.net MVC 4, so should i translate my controllers to Angular or Just use my MVC controllers. What are the pro and cons of using angularJS controllers, can someone please elaborate that? thank you!

Comment: I'm also new to Angular, but as far as I can see your question doesn't make sense because NG-controllers and MVC controllers are very different things. SO i'm not sure a comparison is appropriate/legitimate.

Comment: Whilst asp.net mvc and angular both have models, views and controllers they're situated on different layers. Angular is client side whilst asp.net mvc is server side. It wouldn't make sense to substitute one for the other. They can and should work side by side.

Comment: You can't compare MVC 4 with angular as first is server-side and the second is client-side. I will suggest using MVC 4 to implement server side logic and Angular to implement client-side logic.

Comment: The thing is, if i can get data from API with Angular and with Asp.net controllers.. what should I use? I didn't ask the right question sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `AngularJS` lives in the client, while `ASP.NET MVC` lives in the server. The controllers of `AngularJS` has nothing to do with the controllers of `ASP.NET MVC`. When a web request will be crafted from your browser and it will be send to the server, then a `ASP.NET MVC` controller will find the model and bind it to the view. Then the server will send back to you the rendered view. When your page will be rendered in your browser, the scripts, including those of angular's will be interpreted by the browser's `JavaScript` interpreter. Then each dynamic template you may have defined with angular will be feed with data. Any behavior, like on click of a button or something else that will be handled by your client code has nothing to do with `ASP.NET MVC`. This will be the reign of either `AngularJS` or any other `JavaScript` framework you use.

The only resemblance between `AngularJS` and `ASP.NET MVC` is the fact that they are both two `MVC` frameworks. The `MVC` pattern is in their core.

Comment: I managed to get Data from an API in MVC and in Angular Controllers, so that is what confused me, if i can get data with angular, why not use Just angular.?

Comment: @AlminIslamovic Of course you can use angular controllers to fetch data from any available API you have, either this API is written in ASP.NET MVC or not. This is a decision you have to take alone based on what you want to build. However, an application -I am talking about web applications with dynamic pages, not static files- has a part leaving in the server and a part leaving in the client. Saying leaving, I mean that  you have to write a some server side code, in C#, PHP, JAVA , Python etc that at the end of the day it will end up to an HTTP response, containing html, json whatever.

Comment: @AlminIslamovic That being said, I don't see how you could set aside this and make use only of angular's controllers to build you application.

Comment: What about Routing and Routes? Should i use MVC or Angular Routes Controllers? What is the implementation there

Comment: @AlminIslamovic It's solely depends on how you are planning to use the Angular and ASP.NET MVC. What I am trying to say is that Angular and ASP.NET MVC leaves in different layers and it would be your decision of what are you going to use in each layer from all the tools that you have in disposal.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up. I need a little bit of practice just started as junior programmer these questions must be hell for someone like you, anyway thanks again!

Comment: @AlminIslamovic you welcome dude ! I am glad that I helped. Not at all. All we have questions regardless to the level we are. There is nobody that knows everything.